# django annotate whether exists or not

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a query I'm using:

```
people = Person.objects.all().annotate(num_pets=Count('pets'))
for p in people:
    print(p.name, p.num_pets == 0)
```

(Pet is ManyToOne with Person)

But i'm actually not interested in the number of pets, but only on whether a person has any pets or not. How can this be done?

Comment: As in *annotating*, or *filtering*?

Comment: as in annotating

Comment: you can use `Exists` like `Person.objects.all().annotate(pets_exist=Exists('pets'))`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make use of an [**`Exists`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) to determine if there exists a `Pet` for that `Person`. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Person.objects.annotate(
    has_pet=Exists(Pet.objects.filter(person=OuterRef('pk')))
)
```

Here the model is thus `Pet` that has a `ForeignKey` named `person` to `Person`. If the fields are named differently, then you should of course update the query accordingly.